# How can I export my database from mLAB and imported in Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, mlab, mongodb-atlas

My DBUser has been revoked by mLab and it's because now Atlas owns mLab. So my app can't connect to mLab anymore.

I want to export my database in order to do an import in Atlas later, but since my mLab DBUser is revoked I can not execute this:

```
mongodump -h ds1XXXXX.mlab.com:XXXXX -d iknow -u <user> -p <password> -o <output directory>
```

I'm getting an *Authentication failed message*.

Is there any other way to resolve this export process?

Comment: can you access mLab somehow and create a user?

Comment: @Minsky no, the "add database user" option has been disabled.

Comment: change the pwd of an already existing user?

Comment: No, I can't. Only "delete user" is the unique available option

Comment: i'd ask to them then

Comment: https://docs.mlab.com/mlab-to-atlas/#how-to-migrate